# How to use Android ConstraintLayout component to display any image within a square

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a player screen where I want to display the artwork provided by an audio file as a square. Most files provide a square artwork, but some will provide a rectangle one.
In that case, I want to use the full height of the image and 'zoom in' losing some information on the right and the left but being able to show it in a square.
Right now I failed to do so.
Also, I would like it to work as well if a vertical rectangle is provided

I'm new to Constraintlayout and try the following but that doesn't work

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:filter="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any idea on how to achive this?

Comment: Your layout seems ok. Do you have some screenshot of the undesired result?

Comment: This just displays the image using it's default form and ration which is a rectangle in 16:9 ratio in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` with  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to change the image default form and ration

From the documentation:

> Scale the image using [Matrix.ScaleToFit#FILL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit#FILL)

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:filter="true"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**I am adding the android studio preview so you can see how it looks:**
  [image]